# Compile time check that lcm(a,b) doesn't overflow

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, integer-arithmetic, rational-number

I would like to have a compile-time check that taking the least common multiple of two numbers doesn't overflow.  Difficulty: regarding `std::lcm`,

> The behavior is undefined if |m|, |n|, or the least common multiple of
> |m| and |n| is not representable as a value of type
> std::common_type_t<M, N>.

(**Source**: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/lcm)

Here is what I have come up with:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdint>
#include <numeric>

template<int8_t a, int8_t b,
  std::enable_if_t<
    (std::lcm(a,b) > 0 && (std::lcm(a,b) % a == 0) && (std::lcm(a,b) % b == 0)),
    std::nullptr_t> = nullptr>
void f() { }
```

The rationale here is that that the condition checks that `std::lcm(a,b)` has produced a positive number of type `std::common_type_t<typeof(a), typeof(b)>` which is a multiple of both `a` and `b`.  Given that *some* common multiple of `a` and `b` fits in `std::common_type_t<typeof(a), typeof(b)>`, it follows that the *least* common multiple fits, and therefore we are guaranteed by the definition of `std::lcm` that what we have computed is in fact the lcm.

I checked that this appears to work correctly, e.g.

```
f<3, 5>();      // compiles
f<127, 127>();  // compiles
f<35, 48>();    // doesn't compile
```

However I have a couple of questions.

1. The documentation says that if the least common multiple is not representable, **the behavior is undefined**, and not just implementation-dependent or something.  Does this mean that a program containing something like `f<35,48>()` is ill-formed and that the compiler is welcome to actually compile said code with arbitrary results?
2. Is there a simpler way of doing what I'm trying to do?

I suppose I could write my own constexpr `safe_lcm` function that would guarantee defined behavior and return 0 in the case of an overflow, but that seems like a pretty inelegant solution and also I'd have to work pretty hard to make sure I covered every conceivable combination of arithmetic types I might feed to it.

**Update**: It sounds like undefined behavior isn't allowed in constant expressions.  Since I clearly need this to be a constant expression in order to use it at compile time, does that mean I'm safe here?

**Update 2**: This appears to be a definite strike against the no-undefined-behavior-in-constexpr theory:

```
template<int n> struct S {};

template<int8_t a, int8_t b>
S<std::lcm(a, b)> g()
{
  return S<std::lcm(a,b)>();
}

int main(int, char **)
{
  g<35, 48>(); // compiles :'(
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can't answer the question, but at least in the case of both inputs being 32 bits or less, it should be possible to avoid the possibility of undefined behavior by upcasting them to something double their width before calling the function; even if they're both relatively prime numbers near the ceiling of the data type, the LCM can't exceed twice their bit width. Not a solution to making this work as is, but a possible alternative.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Yeah, but for arbitrary integers types there's no guarantee that I can find a wider type.  I guess maybe I could check that both types have size strictly less than that of intmax_t and then promote both to intmax_t for the conversion?  But of course that then precludes using whatever intmax_t is for the actual arguments.

Comment: Sure. 32 bits of LCM should be enough for anybody, right? ;-) Clearly if they need >32 bit inputs, your template should download and install GMP at compile time and swap in GMP equivalent code using `mpz_class`.

Comment: Instead of `lcm(a,b)`, compute `gcd(a,b)` and use the property `a * b == lcm(a,b) * gdc(a,b)`.

Comment: @j6t Ah, good point.  gcd can't overflow, so I can check that a / gcd(a,b) < MAX / b.  If you want to write that up as an answer I'll accept it.  (The details of the UB-in-constexpr stuff were answered in a separate question I asked.)

Comment: I guess that `std::lcm(int8_t, int8_t)` will incur integer promotion to int and then narrowing back to int8_t. There is therefore no integer overflow and no undefined behavior in the calculations. The result is completely bogus but nothing for the compiler to complain about. ===> the STL is buggy. Mine certainly is, it does no check for narrowing of the result of `a / gcd(a, b) * b`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that both a and b are positive, there is the relationship

```
a * b == lcm(a,b) * gcd(a,b)
```

that you can use to your advantage. Computing gcd(a,b) does not overflow. Then you can check whether

```
a / gcd(a,b) <= std::numeric_limits<CT>::max() / b
```

where CT is `std::common_type_t<decltype(a),decltype(b)>`.